# How to get the DispatcherServlet from spring WebApplicationContext?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

How to get the `DispatcherServlet` instance from a spring `WebApplicationContext` object?

I want to perform a direct request to the the front controller servlet (avoiding the network interface) and check the response from a spring application, e.g. `WebApplicationContext` instance.

Notice, we are not able to use MockMvc to check the HTML rendered by JSP because: "*if you use JSPs, you can verify the JSP page to which the request was forwarded, but no HTML is rendered*"(according to [MockMvc vs End-to-End Tests](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-vs-end-to-end-integration-tests))

So maybe if we get the `DispatcherServlet` instance we could perform the request through its `doDispatch` method and check the content from response.

Comment: You can just do `@Autowired DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet;` to get an instance, but I am not sure if this helps your problem. Can you elaborate a bit what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

**Dispatcher Servlet** : It acts as front controller for Spring based web applications. It provides a mechanism for request processing where actual work is performed by configurable, delegate components. It is inherited from `HttpServlet`, `HttpServletBean` and `FrameworkServlet`. It also implements `ApplicationContextAware` hence it is able to set *ApplicationContext*.

**WebApplicationContext** : It is an extension of a plain ApplicationContext. It is web aware ApplicationContext i.e it has Servlet Context information. When `DispatcherServlet` is loaded, it looks for the bean configuration file of `WebApplicationContext` and initializes it.

So you can set and get the instance of any ApplicationContext from DispatcherServlet but not vice-versa.

```
dispatcherServlet.getWebApplicationContext();
```

Although, you can get an instance of `DispatcherServlet` but I doubt it will serve your purpose as it's scope is `protected`.

```
@Autowired
DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet;
```

Code inside `DispatcherServlet`

```
protected void doDispatch(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
```

It is possible to create your own DispatcherServlet and perform actions. You can override the default one created by Spring boot app.
Sample:

```
public class SampleDispatcherServlet extends DispatcherServlet {

private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

@Override
protected void doDispatch(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    // You can use other implementations of HttpServletRequest and
    // HttpServletResponse as per your requirement
    // e.g. FormContentRequestWrapper , ResourceUrlEncodingResponseWrapper many more
    if (!(request instanceof ContentCachingRequestWrapper)) {
        request = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
    }
    if (!(response instanceof ContentCachingResponseWrapper)) {
        response = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
    }
    HandlerExecutionChain handler = getHandler(request);

    try {
        // Any task to be done
        super.doDispatch(request, response);
    } finally {
        // Some task to be done
    }
  }
}
```

`HandlerExecutionChain`- Handler mapper is used to match current request to appropriated controller. Interceptors are the objects invoked before and after some of dispatching actions

Then we have to register the `DispatcherServlet`:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherRegistration() {
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet());
}

//The bean name for a DispatcherServlet that will be mapped to the root URL "/"
@Bean(name = DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DEFAULT_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_BEAN_NAME)
public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
    return new SampleDispatcherServlet();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you look at
[DispatcherServlet.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/f56d6ea1fbe3e0058b13d127a3170ab1ce0c1e81/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java#L412-L415), there is a constructor with WebApplicationContext as parameter, but the super constructor from [FrameworkServlet.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/f56d6ea1fbe3e0058b13d127a3170ab1ce0c1e81/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/FrameworkServlet.java#L290-L292) does only hold the field itself, without any callbacks - so the given web application context will not know the dispatcher servlet.

So I don't think you can resolve the dispatcher servlet by the WebApplicationContext. Of course you could try to inject/autowire the DispatcherServlet - maybe this is also possible inside tests, but I am not sure.

I think the most easiest way to check for JSP outputs would be to test those parts with a real server as described at [Testing with a running server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.with-running-server) . This should give you the complete output and web application behaviour inside your test without any workarounds.